Can't find libpython3.dll with msys2 compiler and run in native windowns
Currently, I work on embedded python into C
But I encountered a problem which is I can't run this execute in native windows (client require).
Command line run on msys2 is gcc test.c -IC:/msys64/mingw32/include/python3.11 -I. -LC:/msys64/mingw32/lib -lpython3 -llibffi -LC:/msys64/mingw32/lib/python3.11 -lpython3.11 -D__TEST__ 
The setting is already written in C code.
The C code is below
# Setting file
msys2=C:/msys64/mingw32
pythonpath_env=C:/msys64/home/xxx/yyyy
dllDirectory=c:/msys64/mingw32/bin
platlibdir=C:/msys64/mingw32/lib

static void initPy() {
  PyStatus status;
  PyConfig config;

  setEnv("pythonEnv.ini");
  // issue: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/18984
  AddDllDirectory(dllDirectory);
  AddDllDirectory(msys2Path);
  AddDllDirectory(platlibdir);
  AddDllDirectory(pythonEnv);
  //------------------------------
  // Sets config.isolated to 1, and other stuff.
  // But not sufficient by itself.
  PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&config);

  // Provide an explicit path to the Python executable.  Returns a successful
  // status.
  status = PyConfig_SetString(&config, &config.home, msys2Path);
  if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
    printf("Fail set HONE\n");
    goto exception;
  }

  status = PyConfig_SetString(&config, &config.platlibdir, platlibdir);
  if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
    printf("Fail set platlibdir\n");
    goto exception;
  }

  status = PyConfig_SetString(&config, &config.pythonpath_env, pythonEnv);
  if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
    printf("Fail set pythonpath_env\n");
    goto exception;
  }

  status = Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
  if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
    goto exception;
  }

  /* Read all configuration at once */
  status = PyConfig_Read(&config);
  if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
    goto exception;
  }

  return;

exception:
  PyConfig_Clear(&config);
  PyErr_Print();
  /* Display the error message and exit the process with
     non-zero exit code */
  Py_ExitStatusException(status);
}


It is fine to run on msys2 shell but fail on windows native shell.
Note: the execution is compiled with msys2 and run in native windows.
Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?
Thanks.
The answer how to set the environment.

"can't run this execute in native windows" Well, what error do you get? Also, what does which gcc say?

Hi @HolyBlackCat the gcc path is /mingw32/bin/gcc and the issue occurs at runtime (as stated in the title).
